# record the “User Objects” count for iexplorer.exe process in Windows Task Manager

Tags: windows, process, task-manager

Need help record the “User Objects” count for iexplorer.exe process in Windows Task Manager

Please, can someone give me a command for that. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am also wondering how to record the “User Objects” count for iexplorer.exe process in Windows Task Manager

is it the part of the properties or ?